# Module not found: Can't resolve '@material-ui/styles' (React)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

**My dependencies**

```
"dependencies": {
    "@craco/craco": "^6.4.0",
    "@emotion/core": "^10.1.1",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.5.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.3.0",
    "@material-ui/core": "^5.0.0-beta.5",
    "@material-ui/data-grid": "^4.0.0-alpha.37",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.0.5",
    "@mui/material": "^5.0.6",
    "@mui/x-data-grid": "^5.0.0-beta.7",
    "@mui/x-data-grid-generator": "^4.0.2",
    "@mui/x-data-grid-pro": "^4.0.2",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "autoprefixer": "^9",
    "material-ui": "^1.0.0-beta.47",
    "postcss": "^7",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "tailwindcss": "npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
  }
```

I can't use `DataGridPro` but I can use `DataGrid`

The error is

> ./node_modules/@mui/x-data-grid-pro/dist/index-esm.js Module not
> found: Can't resolve '@material-ui/styles'

How to fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the v4 `DataGridPro`:

```
"@mui/x-data-grid-pro": "^4.0.2",
```

Try upgrading the package to v5 so it doesn't depend on the legacy package `@material-ui/styles` anymore:

```
npm i x-data-grid-pro@next
```